# python csv new line

Tags: python, mysql-python

iam using this code to convert db table to csv file, it is  converting in to csv but instead of new line / line breck its using double quotes , can someone help me

```
import MySQLdb
import csv
conn = MySQLdb.connect(user='root',  db='users', host='localhost')
cursor = conn.cursor()
cursor.execute('SELECT * FROM users.newusers')
ver = cursor.fetchall()
ver1 = []
for ve in ver:
    ve = str(ve).replace("', '","|").replace(", '","|").replace(","," ").replace("  "," ").replace("|",",")
    ver1.append(ve)
print ver1
csv_file = open('filename', 'wb')
writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
writer.writerow(ver1)       csv_file.close()
```

current output

```
"(114L,New,9180971675,Ravi Raju,RAJRAVI,National,#N.A,No,No,No,#N.A,OS40,005056BB0803,192.168.0.1,no,yes')","(115L,New,9180971676,Rajendran Mohan,rajemoh,National,#N.A,No,No,No,#N.A,OS40,005056BB0803,192.168.10.10,no,yes')"
```

expected out

```
 114L,New,9180971675,Ravi Raju,RAJRAVI,National,#N.A,No,No,No,#N.A,OS40,005056BB0803,192.168.0.1,no,yes


 115L,New,9180971676,Rajendran Mohan,rajemoh,National,#N.A,No,No,No,#N.A,OS40,005056BB0803,192.168.10.10,no,yes
```

Comment: `ver` is a list of tuples and then you call `str()` on it in `str(ve)`. I can't follow all your `replace` rules but _maybe_ you could just remove `ve = str(ve)...` and just put `ver1.append([str(item) for item in ve])` within your `for` loop and then add any `replace` rules you still need within the list comprehension itself.

Comment: no that also not working

Comment: Do you get an error?

Comment: no error but still there is no line break both out put in the same line

Comment: Try changing `writer.writerow(ver1)` to `writer.writerows(ver1)` note the plural of `writerow`. If `ver1` is a nested list then it should work. `writerow` should be used within a `for` loop.

Comment: now i got it in separate line but due to the missing replace first and last name (third field)  appended with double quotes `114L,New,9180971675,"Ravi,Raju",RAJRAVI,National,#N.A,No,No,No,#N.A,OS40,005056BB0803,192.168.0.1,no,yes`
`115L,New,9180971676,"Rajendran,Mohan",rajemoh,National,#N.A,No,No,No,#N.A,OS40,005056BB0803,192.168.10.10,no,yes`                        it should be Rajendran Mohan/Ravi Raju

Comment: As I said in first comment (though edited so you might have missed). You can still add your `replace` rules in the list comprehension. `ver1.append([str(item).replace(<something>) for item in ve])`

Comment: Working as expected !!! you are super hero

Answer (score 0, accepted):

SQL queries will return results to you in a list of tuples from `fetchall()`. In your current approach, you iterate through this list but call `str()` on each tuple, thereby converting the whole tuple to its string representation.

Instead, you could use a list comprehension on each tuple both to get it into a nested list format and apply your `replace()` operations.

```
for ve in ver:
    ver1.append([str(item).replace(<something>) for item in ve])
```

In the final step you use `csv.writerow()` which is designed to be used within a `for` loop. If your list is nested in the form `[[row1], [row2]]` then you can just change this to writerow**s**. Also, it's best practice to use the context manager `with` to handle files as this will automatically close the file once the operation is completed.

```
with open('filename.csv', 'wb') as csv_file:
     writer = csv.writer(csv_file)
     writer.writerows(ver1)
```